# Similarities and differences between zookeeper and jhipster-registry

Tags: apache-zookeeper, jhipster

I was looking into jhipster-registry and zookeeper. Looks like both of these act as the same. I am not sure though. Is there any similarity between jhipster-registry and zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

JHipster-registry embeds an Eureka server and a Spring Cloud config server with an improved dashboard. So at a high level, it is similar to ZooKeeper with a Spring environment focus.